# Setting a perl exported constant

Tags: perl

I am using a module ([Mail::SPF::Iterator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::SPF::Iterator)) which exports a constant to enable debugging output:

```
use Mail::SPF::Iterator Debug =>1; # enable debugging
```

How can I set this constant later in the code for example depending on a condition?

```
if ( my condition ) {
   # set Debug to 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to [use](http://p3rl.org/use) are just arguments to the `import` method of the used package. The `use` command is run at compile time, so either use a [BEGIN](https://perldoc.pl/perlmod#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END) block

```perl
BEGIN {
    my $do_i_want_to_debug = ... ;
    use Mail::SPF::Iterator Debug => $do_i_want_to_debug;
}
```

or, if you don't know everything needed to decide the value at compile time, use [require](http://p3rl.org/require) instead of `use`:

```perl
my $do_i_want_to_debug = ... ;
require Mail::SPF::Iterator;
Mail::SPF::Iterator->import(Debug => $do_i_want_to_debug);
```

Comment: Thanks: `Mail::SPF::Iterator->import(Debug => $do_i_want_to_debug);` is the solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

A Perl constant is usually just a subroutine definition, so you would say

```
if (condition) {
    no warnings 'redefine';
    *Debug = sub () { 1 };
}
```

Comment: `*DEBUG= sub () { $::some_flag_i_set_or_unset }` :)